# Typescript error "Cannot find name"

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, compiler-errors

I am trying to use the `big.js` library, whose definition is [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/big.js/big.js.d.ts).

Now, this line works:

```
const CONSTANT_1 = new Big(0);
```

Whilst this line:

```
const CONSTANT_2 : Big = new Big(0);
```

causes the error:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Big'.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the second one ?

Comment: Are you importing/referencing that library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at what the first one is implicitly typed as:

[image: BigJsLibrary.BigJS]

**Problem**

The reason that this doesn't work...

```
const CONSTANT_2: Big = new Big(0);
```

...is because `Big` is defined as a variable in the definition file—not a type:

```
declare var Big: BigJsLibrary.BigJS;
```

**Solution**

If you wish to use explicit typing then you need to reference the created type of the constructor...

```
const CONSTANT_2: BigJsLibrary.BigJS = new Big(0);
```

...as is shown in the definition file here:

```
interface BigJS_Constructors {
    new (value: number): BigJS;
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: That works, but looks weird.  Is there a way to change the `.d.ts` to use `Big` like I did?

Comment: @Elena add this statement `type Big = BigJsLibrary.BigJS;`